# Navigation Bar Background Image for full height

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I know those kind of question were asked a lot on Stack its seems that I still confused and can't figure out what is best to do. As far as I understood I should have 2 images for Navigation bar (one is for retina `640x88` and the other for priRetina device `320x44`), that what I have.

On IOS6 everything is working fine. My problem is with IOS7 I want my navigation bar overlap my status bar as apple suggest (don't want to fight them). So I want simple IOS7 appearance. But I always get IOS6 appearance on screens where I show my Navigation bar.
[image]
I tried to `change` it in `Plist` file. I really don't want to go through each controller and add some code (like draw or setFrame). I probably don't understand how NavigationController decide how big the Image should be. I read this [Wrestling with Status Bars and Navigation Bars on](http://blog.jaredsinclair.com/post/61507315630/wrestling-with-status-bars-and-navigation-bars-on-ios-7)  - good one.
Can you please suggest me what to try? (I tried to make the images higher its working but then I got some strange line on Navigation bar)

**Edit1:**

```
//Navigation Controller
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"TapBar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

**Edit2**

I found a work around I created my image with `320x64px` AND I also change the name of it accordingly TapBar64.png. I can not say its good because now for retina and not retina I have the same image.

Comment: Please share your code and Xcode version that you use.

Comment: Tnx Sergey, I simply set the BackgroundImage.

Comment: try to firx this is 64px height of your navigation image for ios7 (44px for nav + 20 px for statusbar). so make navigation image for ios7 with 320x64 px

Comment: Tnx Nitin, its exactly what I did. BUT it never worked out until I changed the name of the Image to TapBar64.png....